# Mpdf is not working after uploading to the host and showing pdf as text if i show it in the browser

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using Mpdf in Laravel and it works well in localhost but after uploading to the host I find the pdf as being shown in the picture when I show it in the browser but if I enable downloading it instead of showing in the browser it showing the text without styling

[the error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn28s.png)

and here is my controller code

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->output();
```

I also tried

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('test');
return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Comment: @KenLee it shows the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem that I have found that after uploading to the server I put the public folder outside the Laravel project which caused the error so I put it again inside the Laravel project and the problem is solved now. thank you